# Designing BJT that's beta value is 120

Tags: bjt, design, semiconductors

I want to design a BJT that's beta value is 120
[image]

Following this picture can I say that the components of the base current are like this?
J(B) = J(pE) + J(R) + J(RB) - J(G) - J(pC0)

I want to design the beta value to be 120 considering durability and productivity together, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: It is a semiconductor physics question more than it is an EE question. What tools are you using and what you done so far? What are the dimensions/ratings for this device? Is it a Si device? You can edit and improve your question after you receive initial comments (or even consider migrating to a more appropriate SE).

Comment: First step is: forget making a BJT with a specific β, you're going to get a really wide range of βs.

Comment: I agree with @Hearth. Designing for a precision \$\beta\$ isn't achievable. Too many things affect it, including temperature and collector current just to name two obvious ones at the model level most of us see a BJT. But that doesn't mean you cannot attempt to push \$\beta\$ in one direction or another. For example, you can reduce \$\beta\$ by making the base wider and increase \$\beta\$ by using a narrow base width. There are costs. For example CE breakdown becomes almost uselessly small for super-beta BJTs (very thin basewidth.) (That can be compensated by a cascode combo, though.)

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Please explain **why** you want to design a transistor with a specific beta. That is a very unusual thing to do.